# replacing terms in a list prolog

Tags: list, replace, prolog

I'm trying to write a prolog program that will take as input a list, an old_subterm and a new_subterm, and return a new list where every instance of old_subterm has been replaced with new_subterm.
So for instance

```
| ?- sub_rep([h(A,g(x)),g(x),g(3)],g(x),p,T).
T = [h(A,p),p,g(3)] ? ;
no
```

So I can get this to work with basic lists, with the following code:

```
replace(E,S,[],[]).
replace(E,S,[E|T1],[S|T2]):-
    replace(E,S,T1,T2).
replace(E,S,[H|T1],[H|T2]):-
    E\=H, 
    replace(E,S,T1,T2).

%(here's some example input/output)

?- replace(b,e,[a,b,c],L).
L = [a, e, c] ;
false.

?- replace(f(Y),g(Y),[f(Y),1,2,f(Y)],L).
L = [g(Y), 1, 2, g(Y)] ;
false.
```

but when I try it with a more complicated list, such as

```
?- replace(g(Y),h,[f(g(Y)),g(Y),g(1)],L).
```

I get the following answer:

```
Y = 1,
L = [f(g(1)), h, h] ;
false.
```

which is not what I'm looking for, since I'm hoping for it to return:

```
? - L = [f(h),h,g(1)] ;
false.
```

I'm new to prolog, and I'm probably missing something obvious, but I don't understand why the variable Y is getting instantiated in this case? It doesn't appear to be a problem in the second example. I imagine it has something to do with the appearance of g(1), but I don't understand why?
Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1):

A first observation on your problem: The lists are of same length! This sounds like a good candidate for `maplist/3`!

```
replace(A, B, As, Bs) :-
   maplist(repl(A,B), As, Bs).
```

So much for the "recursive" part of your problem.  Now, we have to define `repl/4`.
Here is my guess about what you want:

```
repl(A, B, A0, B0) :-
   ( A == A0 -> B = B0 ; A0 = B0 ).
```

Maybe you want some other test in stead of `(==)/2`.

Comment: ah!! i totally forgot about maplist! thanks so much for reminding me! :) hopefully it'll be (smoother) sailing now!

Comment: Alright, I've been staring at this for a while and I'm still kinda running into a wall. To make sure I'm not confused, am I correct in thinking this is something like how the above code works? We use maplist/3 in order to apply the 'partial goal', repl. We give repl the term we'd like to replace and the term we'd like to replace it with, and if A happens to be that term in the list, we replace it with B, otherwise we keep it. 
Assuming this is *somewhat* correct, I'm running into problems with nested compounds, i.e. I can't seem to replace, for instance, a g(X) in [s(f(a,b,g(X))]. Any ideawhy?

Comment: Only elements of the list are replaced, not subterms. But you did not demand this in your original post.

Comment: Ah, yes my apologies! I'd like to be able to replace subterms as well. Am I off base in thinking a reasonable way of going about this would be to replace the 'A == A0' part of repl/4 with another function call, that checks first whether A == A0 and if not, checks if A0 is a compound, and if so =.. it to a list and recurse it?

Answer (score 0):

You should 'explode' your terms for comparison.

```
replace(_, _, [], []).
replace(E, S, [X|T1], [Y|T2]):-
    replace_term(E, S, X, Y),
    !, replace(E, S, T1, T2).
replace(E,S, [H|T1], [H|T2]):-
    replace(E,S,T1,T2).

replace_term(E, S, E, S) :- !.
replace_term(E, S, T, R) :-
      T =.. [F|As],  % explode
      replace(E, S, As, Gs),
      R =.. [F|Gs].  % reassemble
```

test:

```
?- replace(a,b,[a(a),b,c],L).
L = [a(b), b, c] ;
false.


?- replace(g(y),h,[f(g(y)),g(y),g(1)],L).
L = [f(h), h, g(1)] .
```

when there are variables in pattern, things get more complex:

```
?- replace(g(Y),h,[f(g(Y)),g(Y),g(1)],L).
Y = 1,
L = [f(h), h, h] ;
```

Perhaps [numbervars](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=numbervars/3) can help, or we must devise a strategy that instantiate at once the vars...

Comment: I can see how this is a better way of doing this, but I'm still encountering the error above, which is to say

?- replace(g(Y),h,[f(g(Y)),g(Y),g(1)],L).
Y = 1,
L = [f(g(1)), h, h] ;
false.

Any thoughts on why this is happening? Thanks again!